# Cannot Access local Bonobo Git Server home page on IIS

Tags: git, iis, bonobo

I installed the Bonobo Git Server for Windows followed all instructions but instead of being redirected to the home page localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server it instead shows the contents of the application see image below.  What did I do wrong and how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: I rather say you should check the FAQ page which mentions the modules tip I gave you earlier today, and their forum which might also indicate what's up with this. It is very likely that the installation steps missed an `aspnet_regiis` step.

Comment: https://bonobogitserver.com/prerequisites/ check it out and it says all.

Comment: Exactly missed the last step 
'%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir'
lesson learned "don't let excitement get the best of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sir Lex pointed out I missed a very crucial step in the [bonobogitserver.com/prerequisites](https://bonobogitserver.com/prerequisites/).

I forgot to register the MVC framework

- **ASP.NET MVC 4**

  > Don’t forget to register MVC framework with your IIS

*I used the command below and fixed the problem*

> Other - Run `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir with administrator privileges`

Comment: i tried above method but i still have same problem. i used iis 10 on windows 10

Comment: same problem on Windows Server 2016 and IIS10

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to Add ASP.NET 4.6 to server features and roles

[image]